# Duvida Ponteiro c++ em vetores

Tags: c++, ponteiro, memória, algoritmo-de-busca, c++17

Estou tentando mudar o valor de uma item dentro do meu vetor, porém estou utilizando uma função e quando tento mudar o valor por ela, ele acaba passando o valor para outro lugar de memória, tentei utilizar ponteiros porém não consegui.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void FavoritarContato(vector<string> nomes, string nome, vector<bool> favoritos)
{
    int tamanho = nomes.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {

        if (nomes[i]._Equal(nome)) {
            if (favoritos[i]) {
                std::cout << "O contato já está favoritado!";
                std::cout << "\n";
                return;
            }
            favoritos[i] = true;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    vector<string> nomes;
    vector<bool> favoritos;
    string nome = "joao";
    nomes.push_back(nome);
    favoritos.push_back(false);

    FavoritarContato(nomes, nome, favoritos);

    cout << nomes[0] << std::endl;
    cout << favoritos[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: poste algo compilavel...

Comment: Alterado amigo.

Comment: Deve passar o vetor por referência ou por endereço, declarando `vector<>&` ou `vector<>*` para os vetores na função. Um mapa seria talvez melhor que 2 vetores e já poderia associar o nome com o status com `map<string,bool>` talvez

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Veja esse exemplo com as duas opções --- vetor e mapa --- e passando os vetores como referências:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using Banda = map<string, bool>;

void FavoritarContato(
    vector<string>&, string, vector<bool>&);
void mostra(Banda&);

int main()
{
    vector<string> nomes;
    vector<bool>   favoritos;
    string         nome = "joao";
    nomes.push_back(nome);
    favoritos.push_back(false);

    FavoritarContato(nomes, nome, favoritos);
    FavoritarContato(nomes, nome, favoritos); // tenta de novo

    cout << nomes[0] << std::endl;
    cout << favoritos[0] << std::endl;

    cout << "\n\t==> Usando um mapa\n\n";
    cout << std::boolalpha;

    map<string, bool> banda;
    banda.insert({"Johnny", false});
    banda.insert({"Kris", false});
    banda.insert({"Waylon", false});
    banda.insert({"Willie", false});

    mostra(banda);

    // procura um cara e se estiver na banda marca como
    // favorito e depois apaga
    nome       = "Willie";
    auto um    = banda.find(nome);
    um->second = true;
    if (um != banda.end()) // tem esse nome?
    {
        std::cout << "\n"
                  << nome << " favorito? " << std::boolalpha
                  << um->second << "\n\n";
        banda.erase(um); // exclui o cara
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << nome << " nao esta na banda\n";
    }

    mostra(banda);

    return 0;
}

void FavoritarContato(
    vector<string>& nomes, string nome,
    vector<bool>& favoritos)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < nomes.size(); i++)
    {
        if (nomes[i]._Equal(nome))
        {
            if (favoritos[i])
            {
                std::cout
                    << "O contato já está favoritado!";
                std::cout << "\n";
                return;
            }
            favoritos[i] = true;
        }
    }
    cout << nomes.size() << " nomes no vetor\n";
}

void mostra(Banda& banda)
{
    std::cout << banda.size()
              << " elementos no mapa. Favoritos?\n";
    for (auto um : banda)
        cout << um.first << "\t" << um.second << "\n";
};
```

que mostra

```
1 nomes no vetor
O contato jß estß favoritado!
joao
1

        ==> Usando um mapa

4 elementos no mapa. Favoritos?
Johnny  false
Kriss   false
Waylon  false
Willie  false

Willie favorito? true

3 elementos no mapa. Favoritos?
Johnny  false
Kriss   false
Waylon  false
```

Comment: E de novo assim que publicada minha resposta é marcada como inútil, mesmo respondendo a pergunta, e tendo até um código completo como exemplo e a saída. Preciso melhorar ou tratar melhor ex-funcionários :) e o público em geral.

Comment: E depois de aceita pelo autor da pergunta como uma resposta :;